# Print statement does not produce output in spark/scala in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, printing

I have the following program. I have two print statements. I run them in local mode.

```
object SampleApp { 

  def main(args: Array[String]) {   

    Console println "Starting applicaton"

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("MyApplication")
      .getOrCreate()

    val myDataFrame = spark
       .read
       .option("inferSchema", "true")
       .option("header","true")
       .csv("C:\\abc\\def\\Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master\\data\\flight-data\\csv\\2015-summary.csv")
       .repartition(25)

  val top5dest = myDataFrame
      .groupBy("dest_country_name")
      .sum("count")
      .sort(desc("sum(count)"))
      .limit(5)
      .show()

  println("Ending applicaton")   

  }

}
```

The command I use to run the program is:

```
.\bin\spark-submit --class com.spark.??.MyPractice.Dummy  --master local "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\MySparkApp.jar"
```

I my console, I don't see the output of both the print statements. But what I get is the below messages.

```
19/12/05 08:24:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Can you please help me why the output is not shown in the console. Also I tried to redirect the o/p to a file. Even there the above messages are printed; not the statements given in the print statement.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a log4j problem. Do you have a log4j file which is configured ?
I would suggest you to add a log4j file in your resources folder to resolve this issue.

Comment: I am running this code locally in my laptop. Even then it is required?

Comment: yes it would be required .... if you are using spark submit i would recommend adding this property as a system property in your run ...     

```spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="Dlog4j.configuration=file:/filePath/log4j.properties"
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="Dlog4j.configuration=file:/filePath/log4j.properties"```